# How is WP_Query connected to WP_Post in The Loop?

Tags: wp-query, loop

This code works, and I want to understand why.

So I created the object from the `WP_Query` class, and used the `have_posts()` and `the_post()` functions in a while loop.

The question is: since the **`$post->ID`** is a data in an array based on the class `WP_Post`
would this than mean that the object instantiated from the `WP_Post` class is inside the object instantiated from the `WP_Query` class?

Can an object be inside one another? Or am I missing something?

```
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );     
        if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
            <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
                <?php echo '<p>' .$post->ID   .'</p>';?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>       
        <?php else : ?>
            <p>No-data!</p>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I recommend you print_r($the_query) and look at it's structure, it has quite a bit of information you can use inside and outside the loop. have_posts and the_post methods are there to make things easier, but understanding the information inside the query object really helps you see what's at your disposal.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, an object containing other objects is "natural". A `House` object contains an array of `Furniture` objects in its `$furnitures` property... Such as in our case... [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) contains an array of [`WP_Post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post) objects in its `$posts` property... A [one-to-many relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-to-many_(data_model)). This is an [Aggregation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram#Aggregation).

[OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) is all about programatically modelizing things. These things are:

- From the system context, **data** and **process**.
- From the real world context, **entity** and **logic**.

These 2 contexts are relationnal. The **data** is defined by its **entity** and the **process** is defined by its **logic**. These 2 contexts are then transmutable into a common programming pattern - OOP...

The `WP_Post` object is an **entity** holding and defined by - its **data**. It's what we call a [Domain Model Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_model). Though, since it doesn't include any [Domain Logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_logic), design purists may call it an [Anemic Domain Model Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemic_domain_model) instead.

The `WP_Query` object is a **process** (service). In fact, it is defined by the domain **logic** of our `WP_Post` object with for example:

```
$the_query->have_posts();
$the_query->the_post();
```

[The WP Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) itself iterates through the `WP_Query::$posts` and is in charge of switching context (the **global** `$post` object).

From within The Loop:

- `WP_Query::the_post()` initializes the **global** `$post`. You then can access the `$post` data via, for example, `get_the_ID()` or `$post->ID`.
- `WP_Query::have_posts()` checks if there are other `WP_Query::$posts` to iterate through.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [**get_the_ID()**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/), it retrieves the ID of the current item in the WordPress loop:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <?php echo '<p>' . get_the_ID() .'</p>';?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php else : ?>
    <p>No-data!</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: While this answers *the title* it does not answer the bulk of the question asked in the content.